# Syntax error on eval() with json as string

Tags: javascript, json

I'm getting an error `[Exception: SyntaxError: Unexpected token :]` when I try to evaluate the following expression:

```
eval("{"T1": [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12], "T2": [12,11,10,9,8,7,5,4,3,2,1]}")
```

However, the same expression without the `"` works:

```
eval({"T1": [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12], "T2": [12,11,10,9,8,7,5,4,3,2,1]})
```

If my JSON is in string format, like in the first example, how can I convert it into a javascript object?

If I try using:

```
JSON.parse("{"T1": [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12], "T2": [12,11,10,9,8,7,5,4,3,2,1]}")
```

I get `[Exception: SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier]`. How can I escape the `"`?

Comment: Perhaps you could use something from here: [Link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/45015/safely-turning-a-json-string-into-an-object)

Comment: That isn't JSON. If it was, T1 and T2 would be surrounded by `"` not `'`. Fix that and use a real JSON parser, not `eval`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Avoid using `eval` (see [why](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/197769/when-is-javascripts-eval-not-evil)), use [`JSON.parse`](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Using_native_JSON) when available. To support older browsers, I suggest using a third-party library like [Crockford's](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js).

On your second example, it works because there is nothing to be parsed, you already have an object.

**EDIT**: you added one more question, here is the answer: you escape `"` with `\`. For example, this is a valid string containing just a quote: `"\""`.

Answer (score 3):

The curly braces are interpreted to be a code block, not a object delimiter. Therefore you'll get an exception for the colon.

You can work around that by surrounding your object with (), but better use `JSON.parse`. Don't forget: eval is evil :-)

Answer (score 1):

You need parentheses, but really, use `JSON.parse` as bfavaretto suggested.

To understand why your current code is failing, consider that

```
eval("{}")
```

runs the program

```
{}
```

which is just a block containing no statements while

```
eval("({})")
```

runs the program containing a single statement which evaluates the expression `{}`, an empty object.

Answer (score 0):

What's the point of just evaluating an json object without actually assigning it to any variable?

It seems kind of pointless to me.

eval isn't a dedicated json parser. It's JS parser and it's assuming that the {} is a block of code.

This however works

```
eval("var abc = {'T1': [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12], 'T2': [12,11,10,9,8,7,5,4,3,2,1]};");
```

As everyone stated, use JSON.parse if you really need to parse json. Eval is dangerous.